# Selenium with firefox-geckodriver on Raspbian 64bit?

Tags: python, selenium, raspberry-pi, raspbian, geckodriver

is possible to run automatic scripts (Python + Selenium) with firefox-esr browser on Rasberry Pi OS (Raspbian) 64 bit?

In the past I used Ubuntu XFCE on my Raspberrypi Pi 4 and there was possible to install geckodriver (like `sudo apt install firefox-geckodriver`).

When comes official 64 bit Raspbian I removed Ubuntu and switched to Raspbian.

But on Raspbian OS I have problem with installing geckodriver.
Error: `E: Unable to locate package firefox-geckodriver`

I don't want to use Chromium and chromedriver.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mozilla finally releases Geckodriver 0.32 for AArch64 which works on Raspbian 64bit (Debian based).